# Polynomial (third degree)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

A third degree polynomial $p(x)=0$ when $x=1$ and $x=3$. We also learn that $p(x) \geq 0 $ when $x \geq 1$ and $p(2) =2$. Determine $p(x)$. How should I proceed? I presume no calculus is needed.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $p(x) = a(x-1)(x-3)(x-b)$ and only for one value of $b$ this polynomial doesn't change its sign around the point $x=3$.

Comment: So, the answer should be $p(x)=2(x-1)(x-3)^{2}$.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$